# Getting builtins.ValueError View function did not return a response

Tags: flask, valueerror

I just started learning flask and I am stuck on this error. I have checked many such questions here but I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
from flask import Flask,url_for
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from WebService.application import deploy_azure

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def my_form():
    return render_template("xyz.html")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.form['text']
    resp = make_response(deploy_azure.deploy_function(data))
    return resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: What is deploy_function(data)?

Comment: I am calling a function from different python script and passing it to the make_response

Comment: There is something wrong with your `resp` that your return. What does `deploy_function` return? I don't see that you import it in your code. I can only see `deploy_azure`.

Comment: What are you trying to return? A template or a string?

Comment: Trying to return a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and you want to return a string returned by the `deploy_function` method in the flask view then just return it. Don't use `make_response` in this case. Your method should look like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.form['text']
    return deploy_azure.deploy_function(data)
```

You also have the same route defined for two different view functions. Although it will work, but it's better to use different routes for different functions.

Comment: @user144526 Could you show the output of `type(deploy_azure.deploy_function(data))`?

Comment: deploy_function was the one not returning, it is solved. Thanks for the help :D